# How to predicts with conditions and limitations?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

The dataframe has the following features:

```
+--------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+-----+-------+
|        | id     | weight | type | value | export | tax | total |
+--------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+-----+-------+
| 0      | 1      | 4      | 1    | 10    | 1      | 5   | 15    |
+--------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+-----+-------+
| 1      | 2      | 3      | 1    | 12    | 1      | 6   | 18    |
+--------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+-----+-------+
| 2      | 3      | 8      | 2    | 15    | 0      | 0   | 15    |
+--------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+-----+-------+
| ...    | ...    | ...    | ...  | ...   |        | ... | ...   |
+--------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+-----+-------+
| 123004 | 123005 | 5      | 2    | 12    | 0      | 0   | 12    |
+--------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+-----+-------+
```

The **tax** column should be predicted. It is important to consider the relationship between **tax** and **export** .

When **export** == 1 then **tax** is there.

The following code (Random forest as an example) predicts the tax without considering this rule.

```
y = df['tax']
X = df.drop(columns=['tax'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split# Split the data into training and testing sets
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=10, random_state=101, n_estimators =42)

rf.fit(train_X, train_y);

predictions = rf.predict(test_X)
```

Questions:

1- How to tell the algorithm to consider the above rule?

2- The **tax** cannot be more than the **value**. How is it possible to set limitations or a range for the prediction?

3- If there is other method to predict the same result please mention it. (Random forest is not a must)

4- I am beginner in this field so good ideas for this sample are very welcome.

Comment: perhaps monotone constraints might help, https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/monotonic.html

Comment: @MiguelTrejo thank you for the tip. I marked it as useful. I am a beginner so it is a bit complicated how we can fit this method on this sample.